# Struts2 404 page not found

Tags: struts2

I am creating my first application with Struts2.
after entering filter mapping in web.xml file getting page not found error

**Web.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
    <display-name>STRUTS</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <filter-class>
            org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

index.jsp

```html
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Product</title>
</head>
<body>
Proudct want to disply
</body>
</html>
```

**Error :** 
HTTP Status 404 - /STRUTS/index.jsp

---

type Status report

message /STRUTS/index.jsp

description The requested resource is not available.

---

Apache Tomcat/7.0.53

Kindly help!! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your index.jsp file location is not mapped properly

Comment: i placed my index.jsp file parallel to web-content. and if i remove that filter and its mapping, it is working fine...but after addition it shows error  HTTP Status 404 - /STRUTS/index.jsp

Comment: For help http://stackoverflow.com/a/16532473/573032